# oracle apex branches - page redirect

Tags: oracle, branch, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

i have an interactive form. after an insert or update on any particular form i would like the form to be submitted if it passes validation and there is no errors AND THEN i would like to be redirected to another page in the application.

I created a branch to execute and redirect to 'page 2' for example using 'after processing' as the point of execution and 'Page or URL (Redirect)' as behavior. the branch works fine - it validates before etc etc. however upon a successful form insert or update, the form submits but does not redirect me to my chosen page.

any reasons as to why?

Answer (score 1):

Procedures, as well as branches, "fire" in order determined by the sequence value.

So, if - for example - one procedure raises an error, the rest of them aren't executed.

The same goes for branches - check whether there are several of them (for example, one that leaves you on this page; another which returns you to an interactive report; yet another one which redirects to some other page). If one of those branches *branches* first, the rest of them won't "work".

Therefore:

- check their sequence
- check server-side conditions

  - use `when button pressed` property so that Apex knows which branch to use when certain button is pressed
  - additionally, see whether you can do something with condition's `type`

Also, enable debugging, run the page and view debug info - it'll show what's going on and, hopefully, let you understand what you should do to fix the issue.